# LaTeX Compilation Problem: revtex4-1.cls Not Found

Tags: revtex

I'm using TeXmaker with MikTeX2.9 on Windows 7.

Recently I've installed revtex4-1 according to the instructions in the README file.

However when I tried to compile the sample `.tex` file using TeXmaker, I got the error "revtex4-1.cls", when this file was indeed present in the folder which I had included in the MiKTeX search paths.

I've tried to install TeXLive (a LaTeX editor) as suggested by someone on the web, but I couldn't get it installed for some reasons.

So what's wrong with my REVTeX installation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please give us some code, which results in your problem. The error is just "revtex4-1.cls"? That's not very informative. TeXLive is no editor (at least I don't know it) but a TeX distribution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Real quick: TeXLive is not an editor, but a TeX distribution (just like MikTeX is). Various editors -- aka "front ends" can be used with either MikTeX or TeXLive. Regarding your attempt to install `revtex4-1` in MikTeX: Did you use MikTeX's own Package Manager program or did you install the package "by hand"? If it's the latter, did you remember to update MikTeX's filename database by clicking on the "Update FNDB" button in the MikTeX "Settings" helper program?

Comment: Have you tried installing it via MiKTeX? Just open the MiKTeX Package Manager and search for revtex.

Comment: Just a follow up on @LaRiFaRi's suggestion: To get `revtex4-1`, you'll need to install the `revtex` bundle via MikTeX's Package Manager utilility, and not (admittedly somewhat surprisingly) the `revtex4` bundle.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The problem has been solved. In fact one did not need to do any installation when using Texmaker. When one compiles a tex file that uses revtex, it will prompt you to install the revtex package. One has to choose to install it from the internet (or a folder, rather than through a random repository). Then it shall work out fine.